# Inverse of $f(x)=x+\sin(x)$

Tags: inverse-function, elementary-functions

I'm attempting to find $$f^{-1}(x)$$ for the function $$f(x) = x + \sin{x}.$$ So far I've tried some simple algebraic methods as well as rewriting $\sin{x}$ as a power series. I'm not quite sure where to go aside from that. Any direction would be appreciated!

Comment: While the inverse does exist, there isn't really a way of expressing it using elementary functions. 
You might like to check out this related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257873/why-isnt-the-inverse-of-the-function-x-mapsto-x-sinx-expressible-in-terms?rq=1

Comment: Why do you need the inverse? What are you trying to us it for? Depending on that different forms of non-closed form inverses may be differently useful.

Comment: This question already has an answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257873/why-isnt-the-inverse-of-the-function-x-mapsto-x-sinx-expressible-in-terms/2623859#2623859