# How do you solve $\sin(x) = x$ with algebra?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I'm making a quick program in excel to calculate the height of a ball over time and I need to know when it will hit a vibrating plate.
I cannot find a way in which to make the formula say x = [something]

$$A\sin(2\pi fx)+A = (((ax)^2)/2a)+h$$

If you have spare time solving this one would be of great help too:

$$V(x-t)-a(x-t)^2 = A\sin(2\pi fx)+A$$

If you only have enough time for one or only feel like doing one, that's also okay.

Thanks for anyone's help in advance.

edit:
Someone asked what the variables meant so I'm here to specify
A = Amplitude (in my case 0.0075m)
x = the variable (time)
f = frequency (in my case 10 hertz, however in the program I'm making I would like to be able to change the frequency)
h = height at which the ball is dropped (in my case 0.2m)
V = speed of the ball after it's thrown upwards by an outside force

Comment: Both are impossible to solve exactly.  The best you can do is use an approximate method, like Newton's method, for example.

Comment: @tilper Has it been proved that it cannot be solved exactly or has a method just not been found as of yet?

Comment: @David, tilper said what he meant, and meant what he said.

Comment: Can you please specify ,exactly what $A,x,f,h,V$ are?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson how does one go about proving that?

Comment: @David, you may find http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257873/why-isnt-the-inverse-of-the-function-x-mapsto-x-sinx-expressible-in-terms helpful.

Comment: @GerryMyerson a tilper is faithful 100%.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson thank you.

Comment: It is not possible to solve a combination of *algebraic and transcendental* functions using *algebra*

Comment: The title has little to do with the question. Solution to $\sin x=x$ is $x=0$.